# How to write in a file at specific position or before/after specific string in php?

Tags: php, file-handling

I'm using php to perform read/write operation in a txt file. Currently I am using fseek($file,0) and if I am using "a" mode with fopen() it add the text at last and if I'm using "c" or "rw+" mode then it replace the string at the beginning of text file. If I increase the position number suppose to 10 then it leave the first 10 character and after that add string by replacing the existing text in file.

What I want to achieve is, not to overwrite the text in the file, just append at that position.

And is there any way in which, I append the text not by giving position number, just search the specific keyword in the file and append the text at that position.

**abc.php**

```
<?php 

    $val = "string";
    echo $val;
    $myfile = fopen("demo.txt", "c") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fseek($myfile, 0);
    fwrite($myfile, $val);
    fclose($myfile); 
?>
```

**demo.txt**

```
this is some text
this is some text
this is some text
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve (how the file starts off and how it should end up looking like) as well as code you have already tried.

Comment: @NigelRen see, I update my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$all = file_get_contents("file");
$find = strpos($all, "needle");
$write = substr($all, 0, $find) . "insert" . substr($all, $find);
file_put_contents("file", $all);
```

The way filesystems work is that you cannot insert bytes in the middle. You need to overwrite all the contents behind if you have to insert something in the middle.

If the performance impacts do not suit your needs, you might want to use a database format to save data.

Or if you don't want to learn to use a database, a "convenient" way is to adding padding bytes between units in the file so that you can overwrite those padding bytes without having to move the bytes behind. This is actually how most implementations of filesystems and databases prevent overhead when inserting in the middle is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Your answer gave me a hint to achieve the solution, by getting the string position and then append the upcoming string at that position.